# BufLeave: Auto save split file not working

Tags: autocmd, split, save

I usually keep `*.in` files open in split and edit them. I would like vim to autosave the `*.in` files whenever I switch between splits.

Searching other answers I found `BufLeave` that suits my case. I have below in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufLeave *.in :w!<cr>
```

But this gives below error when I switch out of the split that has a `*.in` file open:

```
Error detected while processing BufLeave Auto commands for "*.in":
E13: File exists (add ! to override)
```

I am able to normally execute `:w` and `:w!` in the vim window successfully, but this auto save short cut is not working.

My vim details

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Dec  3 2019 04:38:39)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283, 1365
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

What could be the issue? Any help?

Comment: check your existing BufLeave autocommand. Perhaps an old autocommand without the `!`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a while before I saw it. The problem is the`<cr>`.
Try:

```
augroup autosave_buffer
  au!
  au BufLeave *.in :w
augroup END
```

If you check your current directory, you will find a file named `'<cr>'`.

Comment: Wow, great find! I completely missed that too. Wondering why this was causing it to execute the write on the wrong window for some reason...

Comment: @filbranden I guess (speculate) there are two things here: 1) Might be that there was another autocmd for BufLeave without the `!` (augroup not mentioned). And 2) The autocmd wrote to the file `<cr>`. So the E13 was not about the`*.in` or the other file, but for the file `<cr>`. Finally I learned that `:wralf` results in an error, but `:w(ralf` would create the file `(ralf`. Any `[^A-z]` starts a file name. And btw: Great to see you & Ben on the mod candidate list. Just my first thought.

Comment: Ah yeah good call! Now I recall seeing a file named `'<cr>'` in a directory and wondering where it was coming from. It was definitely from trying to reproduce this one! So that's why the original mapping was failing.